# What is the noun for “to resume”?

Tags: word-choice

If "to assume" is an "assumption".
What is the noun for "to resume".

Resume as in: pause and resume; to pursue again.

Comment: A resumption. But this question seems very elementary. Any dictionary could give you this.

Comment: Wow.. can't believe is that obvious. I discussed with the office where some believes (include myself) 'resumption' is related to 'revenge' while others think 'resumption' isn't a real word...

Comment: You must've confused it with *redemption*

Comment: @Philoto, ARRHHHH... thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Resumption, as Sam stated above. Or you could go with continuation.

Comment: Desperate? Perhaps. But I think eager is a better description.